# Service Fabric - business case for reliable service or actors

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In commercial lending two different applicants (Individual or Company) can request a loan using the same collateral (house, car, business...).

In this case an applicant can be actor, looks natural to me.

How about collateral? - Actor or Service?

In my opinion:
Actors are an abstraction done on top of a reliable service in SF. The actor model have concepts (reminders, timers, re-entrancy, events and so for), to help with the reasoning of implementing business requirements, but it has a bigger learning curve to understand these concepts and to apply actor patterns:
https://acom-swtest-2.azurewebsites.net/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-patterns-introduction/

Reliable services are in my opinion a more raw approach to architect requirements, we only get a Run async method to hook operations for doing pooling, batching and rpc calls for request/reply pattern. 
Stateful reliable service come with the complexity of thinking in partition, thinking in a proper algorithm for creating partition key according to business requirements, but we are on control in doing our own patterns. We can have collection to hold hot data for read and write, (no just cache) to reduce latency (better performance).

Which approach you take?.

Take in consideration: 
- you have to deliver quick and your development team is new to service fabric and actor model.
- we are not doing reactive programming, no streams of data neither.

Would you start with Stateful service?. 
Can we make those stateful service stateful actors later? - if need be.

I'm not comfortable in pointing the company to go with actor with little expertise.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think anyone can make a decision for you. They are just different programming models running on top of the same runtime. Actors do require some learning, but also provide some obvious benefits (no concurrency, easy partitioning and communication).

Comment: As said it's a decision specific to your needs. We're currently making a similar decision and because of our needs is down to either Actors or a class equivalent to the actor state being stored in a dictionary. Actors feel the better fit but we will have times where we need to query Actors based on x, y or z property, which while technically possible isn't recommended

Comment: Agree that down to the details will allows us to see which is a natural fit but we don;t have this luxury in most company, and people in seniors position usually don"t get involved in these awesome details conversation. 

Actors in hot place can become bottle neck, specially if the operation is slow. We can also get into deadlock, or we need to put in place timeout  to deal with bidirectional communication between actors. I'm looking for industry learnign in these areas, but I'm understand that there is not a wrong answer just an slily better approach for some cases. Thanks.